# Oracle SQL creating user and granting permissions

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL and programming so I apologize if this isn't clearly worded.

I have the following code to create a user and role. I want `user1` to be able to select and view `table1`.

1. When I run this code `user1` isn't able to select `table1` and I get the error that the table does not exist.
2. When prompted with the Database Entry screen I input user and password.
3. When prompted with the statement `"Enter TNS_ADMIN entry or blank for Current Worksheet Database:"` I don't input anything.

`USER1` is able to connect, but not view the table. Under "other users" in the connection I see `USER1` but none of the tables I've established are listed.

Thanks!

```
CREATE USER user1 
    IDENTIFIED BY user1
    DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
    TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
    ACCOUNT UNLOCK;

CREATE ROLE ReadOnly;
GRANT SELECT ON table1 to ReadOnly;
--GRANT SELECT ON table2 to ReadOnly;
--GRANT SELECT ON table3 to ReadOnly;
GRANT CONNECT to user1;
GRANT ReadOnly to user1;

grant create session to user1;

connect user1
show user

select * from table1
```

Comment: Under which user are you creating user1? Is table1 owned by the user who creates user1?

Comment: Thanks for reading. Yes, table1 is owned by the user who creates user1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `table1` is not owned by `user1`, you have three options

You can use the full name of the table in your query

```
SELECT * FROM <<schema name>>.table1
```

You can create a synonym for `table1`.  A private synonym in the `user1` schema would generally be preferred but a public synonym would also work.  As `user1`

```
CREATE SYNONYM table1 FOR <<schema name>>.table1

SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Or you can change the default schema (for name resolution purposes, this has no impact on privileges)

```
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema=<<schema that owns table1>>

SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm having trouble referencing the schema to input the full name of the table. Is the schema name the name of the connection? I'm using Oracle SQL Developer and have 1 "connection" which is named rds-connection. Would the dash ("-") be an issue? Using your first solution I'm inputting: select * from rds-connection.table1   Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @kmd - The name of the connection in SQL Developer is irrelevant.  What user did you log in as to create the table?

Comment: I logged in as a user which I created when I made an AWS database and input this as a "master user". The user name is ORACLEUSER and is the one which I created all tables with. Does that answer the question?

Comment: @kmd - if you logged in as OracleUser to create the tables, OracleUser is the schema that owns the table and the schema name you'd need to use in your queries.